# Setting the service details for several reviews with structured data

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, structured-data

I'm doing up a testimonials page and recently I have been utilising [structured data](http://schema.org/) to help SE's find the reviews more easily; as per the [review information](http://schema.org/Review) found.

Now, normally if I was doing *one* review I would do something like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
        <span itemprop="provider">Business Name</span>
        <span itemprop="serviceType">Service Provided</span>
        <span itemprop="url">http://www.example.com/</span>
    </div>
    <div class="review" itemprop="reviewBody">Great service - thanks!</div>
    <div class="other">
        <p class="name" itemprop="author">Joey Bigs</p>
        <p class="details">Owner, <a href="">Joes Treats</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, what if I wanted to do a page that had *several* reviews for the same thing; do I need to repeat the below information for *each* review or can I just display it once?

```
    <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
        <span itemprop="provider">Business Name</span>
        <span itemprop="serviceType">Service Provided</span>
        <span itemprop="url">http://www.example.com/</span>
    </div>
```

If I only need to include it once - how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Microdata’s `itemref` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#attr-itemref) to reference the item that gets reviewed, so you don’t have to repeat it for each review:

```
<div id="foo" itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
  <!-- make sure that this element is not a child of another itemscope -->
</div> 

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemref="foo"></div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemref="foo"></div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemref="foo"></div>
```